# Bad Link to download a trial data for OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap

When I selected any option to download data in OpenStreetMap, i cant download data with the following error: Invalid key or download temporarily unavailable!

Any idea?

Regards
IB

Comment: Where exactly did you try to download data from?

Comment: What exactly do you want to download, and how?

I assume you are trying the OSM API via HTTP?

If you want to download data for a specific reason, then services like the GeoFabrik extracts on http://download.geofabrik.de/ or the BBBike extract service  on https://extract.bbbike.org/ might be a better choice?

Comment: when I launch a new container, enter in host:port, and then i follow the steps to install. When i selected the type of map, i got the generate link to download the map, but in this step, my download fail because this links is invalid.